# Did Ridley Scott include slowly rotating fans in Prometheus?

Tags: ridley-scott, prometheus

In most (or all) of Ridley Scott movies there is at least one scene with slowly rotating fans. Sometimes light is shining from behind the fan casts shadows on a heavy smoke atmosphere. This is very evident in Blade Runner and Alien. There is also a scene with a slowly rotating fan in Black Rain, and even in Gladiator it is simulated with palme leaves (or feathers maybe).

Is there a scene with a slowly rotating fan in Prometheus?

Comment: On second viewing I didn't see a slow fan, but there is scene where burning incense emits thick, milky smoke directly under a bright light

Comment: when does that happen?

Comment: Shaw is burning incense under a bright, desk-lamp-sized light when Holloway enters her room at the start of their love scene

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no scenes in *Prometheus* with slowly rotating fans.

Not sure how I can cite or backup a *lack* of something, but I have seen the movie a couple of times.

Answer (score 3):

The trademark fan image is done differently in Prometheus, so you have to look closely. Notice the radiating scanning lasers when the mapping drones fly through the tunnels of the pyramid.